# SSL Certificate Issue in splunk add-on when making API calls to our Server Product

Tags: ssl, splunk, splunk-cloud

So I have been trying to submit the splunk add-on,but this is the feed back I have received from the Splunk Team:

> Technical Add-On for Splunk did not qualify for Splunk Cloud
> compatibility for the following reasons:
>
> If you are using requests.post to talk to your own infra with
> non-public PKI, make sure you bundle your own CA certs as part of your
> app and pass the path into requests.post as an arg.

We are using requests.post in my app to make API calls to our product server from Splunk. After the initial response from the App Review team, we added an option for the users to add a location to their own certificate which is then used in the requests.post. Code below should execute if the path to the certificate is provided by the user:

```
response=requests.post(url=url,headers=headers,json=temp_container, timeout=60,verify=certloc)
```

Or the code below should execute when path to the certificate is not provided:

```
response=requests.post(url=url,headers=headers,json=temp_container, timeout=60,verify=False)
```

But I am getting the same response as above from the review team on the second code where I have kept verify=False.
I was planning to remove the second code and make it mandatory for the user to add the path to the SSL certificate. But in this link: https://community.splunk.com/t5/Splunk-Cloud-Platform/How-do-I-go-about-publishing-a-Splunk-Technical-Add-On/m-p/633127 it says that the certificate needs to be in the default folder of the package. "Does that mean we set up a private CA, generate the certificate, and bundle it with the app?
Why do we still need to bundle the certificate when we have given it as an option to the end user?
Lastly, if we generate the certificate, can the same certificate be used by all app users when we distribute the package? In our case, every customer has their own instance of our product just like every user has their own Splunk instance.Or the user has to place their SSL certificate in the default folder inside the package before they can use my app?
My app is fully complete but this issue is persistence so any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When utilizing the Splunk add-on for our Server Product, we encountered a critical SSL certificate issue while making API calls. This problem stemmed from a mismatch between our server's certificate and the one Splunk expected. As a result, secure communication between the two systems was compromised, leading to potential data vulnerabilities. Resolving this SSL certificate mismatch is imperative to ensure the integrity and security of our API interactions. Immediate action is required to update and synchronize the certificates, restoring the trust and confidentiality of data transmissions between Splunk and our Server Product.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. May I know how did you synchronize the certificates? You are adding the server certificate to the splunk add on package?